Java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol 'AAsset_close' in libreactnativejni.so on Android
What could be causing this UnsatisfiedLinkError, particularly the cannot locate symbol "AAsset_close"?
Are there any known compatibility issues with libreactnativejni.so and the NDK versions that could lead to this error?
How can I resolve this issue to ensure the application loads the native libraries correctly?



I have ensured that all native libraries are correctly included and that they are compatible with the application's architecture.

Verified that the NDK and build configurations are properly set up.

Cleaned and rebuilt the project multiple times.


